# Rendering <code> tag within template gives tag <object> has no matching end tag error

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to render a code snippet in my index.vue file using the following vue component.

```
<CodeSnippet>
  <code>
   <pre>
     public TokenAuthenticationAttribute() : base(typeof(AuthorizeAction))
     {
       Arguments = Array.Empty<object>();
     }
   </pre>
 </code>
</CodeSnippet>
```

When saving the file I get the following compiler error in VS code.

```
Errors compiling template:
    
tag <object> has no matching end tag.
```

I understand that it thinks `<object>` is a html tag and is expecting a closing tag `</object>` but that's not possible as this is a c# code snippet.

Is there any way to emit compiling of the text within a  block or any way around this? I've tried using v-pre on the code tag but it hasn't helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got around this by using the HTML name code for the < > symbols instead.

& lt; and & gt;

Answer (score 1):

```js
<CodeSnippet>
  <code>
   <pre>{{ `
     public TokenAuthenticationAttribute() : base(typeof(AuthorizeAction))
     {
       Arguments = Array.Empty<object>();
     }
   ` }}</pre>
 </code>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't solve the issue and the compiler still complained about the same error!